# Issues while deploying Giraph

Tags: hadoop, installation, giraph

I am trying to deploying Giraph in order to run some examples. I follow the [QuickStart guide](http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html), skipping the step Deploying Hadoop, because I have already set up hadoop on my machine as a single node. However I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.4:process (default) on project giraph-parent: Error finding remote resources manifests: /opt/giraph/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.4:process (default) on project giraph-parent: Error finding remote resources manifests
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error finding remote resources manifests
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.processResourceBundles(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:1168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.execute(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:470)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/giraph/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.processResourceBundles(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:1076)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong? FYI. I have hadoop-1.2.1 and giraph-1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the mvn command in the giraph base folder (here you can see folders like giraph-core, giraph-examples, etc)?

If you are using Hadoop  1.2.1 then specify to mvn to build it for Hadoop 1 by mentioning -Phadoop_1 flag.

I'm not sure but I think maven downloads dependencies over the internet so make sure your internet connection is working and maven can connect to the internet.

I have Hadoop 1.2.1 and Giraph 1.1.0, maven version 3, and jdk 7. It worked for me just by following the quick start guide + adding -Phadoop_1 command.

Comment: I have same error. Maybe the problem is that is try to deploy the giraph 1.1.0-snaphot? How can i clone the steady version?

Comment: @salvador try this (from terminal) : `wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/apache/giraph/archive/release-1.1.zip`